# MongoDB: first argument must be string or Buffer?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I am trying to write all the documents in a mongoDB collection to my web site. My code:

```
mongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/database', function(err, db) {
if (err) throw err

var cursor = db.collection("Users").find();

while(cursor.hasNext()){
    res.write(cursor.next())
}

res.end()
```

But I get the error first argument must be a string or buffer. Why is that? How can I parse the above data into a string then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following snippet, Am assuming resp is http response.

```
mongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/database', function(err, db) 
{
  if (err) throw err
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");
  db.collection("Users").find({}).toArray(function(err, dbres) {
                    console.log("select : ", dbres);
                    db.close();
                    resp.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json"});
                    resp.write(JSON.stringify(dbres));
                    resp.end();
            });
}
```

Comment: Same error, first argument must be string or buffer

Comment: are you getting error in line `resp.write(dbres);` ?